# boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-asio, boost-thread, firebreath

I need some help with this exception, I am implementing a NPAPI plugin to be able to use local sockets from browser extensions, to do that I am using Firebreath framework.

For socket and connectivity I am using Boost asio with async calls and a thread pool of 5 worker threads.
Also I have a deadline per thread to implement a transmission timeout.

My extension workflow with the plugin is as this:

1. Open socket 1(this starts a async_receive and the deadline
   async_wait)
2. Write in the socket 1
3. Get response 1
4. Open another socket 2
5. Write in the socket 2
6. Write socket 1
7. Close socket 1
   (socket.cancel(), deadline.cancel(), socket.shutdown(), socket
   release).
8. Get response 2
9. Write socket 2
10. Close socket 2

As everything is cross language and async is really hard to debug but all open, write or close are called from javascript and the read from socket 1 that calls open 2, write 2,  write 1 and close 1 in that order.

Maybe evrything I am telling is unrelated as the call stack when the exception is thrown does not show any of my functions and only show that it is inside a `malloc` that calls `_heap_alloc_dbg_impl`

As it is it usually fails in the 2nd or 3rd full cycle and it seems that happens between steps 5 and 7.

But, I think that it must be asio related as doing everything with a single worker thread just crashes with the exception on the first cycle.

I am open to publish more information code if you need it.

**Update 1:**

[image: VS when breaking]

**Update 2:**

There are 10 threads are launched with:

```
workPtr.reset( new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service));

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    m_threadGroup.create_thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) );
}
```

The 11th _threadstartex I don't know who launched it

On another thread (not the one that VS claims as causing the crash) there is a `join_all()` in process because my class is being destroyed but I think it shouldn't, so maybe this crash is due to another exception and the Firebreath process to close everything when it crashes.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? Post some code.

Comment: How many worker threads are there?  It looks like the threads you're starting never reach completion.

Comment: Added image with code, call stack and threads. I am unable to see the exception, I just get the message about a exception with the options to break or continue and when I break that is the state, note that there is no frame with my code in the call stack (my classes are SocketInfo, SocketsApi, Base64), on another thread it is clear that npapi object it has been destroyed and it is doing a {m_threadGroup.join_all();} but it shouldn't be destroyed at that point, so maybe VS is breaking after another exception caused the plugin to start the destruction, I have no idea of how FB works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the errors by continuing to inspect the other threads. I found that my principal class that Firebreath was invoking was in the process of being destroyed. Inspecting a little more I found that it was totally my fault I have a class for storing the sockets information that needed to use a function in the principal class (I didn't like it but it was the only way I found to use it) so I added a `shared_ptr` to the principal class. So if it after destroying on of those `SocketInfo` objects as there were no others the ptr ref count reached 0 and the principal class was being destroyed.

What is fun is that sockets usually close normally after being used so I see no reason why this was not triggered when there were not sockets opened and only happened when 2 sockets where opened and closed in a row.

Anyway I also had a `shared_from_this` error with the deadline handler but that seemed unrelated.

And now it seems it is working as expected with any number of threads.

Comment: I edited this to remove the apologetic tone, SO encourages answering your own question. So +1 for an answer that will hopefully help others.